# Examples of non-filtered abelian categories

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

I was curious about how to find sufficiently many examples of small non-filtered abelian categories that appear naturally?

I thought of the category of vector spaces with a fixed basis that seems to be non-filtered, but is there any more good examples? (Is my example even correct?)

(For reference: I'm trying to solve the following problem: is it true that colimit of representable functors over comma category is left exact iff the comma category is filtered)

---

Edit: Is it true that if a small abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ is filtered its category of elements (i.e. comma category $(*\downarrow \mathcal{A}))$ is filtered? (I suppose no, but are there any counterexamples?)

Comment: If by filtered you mean that every finite diagram has a cone, then every category with finite limits is filtered.

Comment: @ArnaudD. So is it true that the comma category of a small abelian category is filtered? (Since in abelian category there are obviously finite limits/colimits)

Comment: The co-slices of a category with finite (co)limits also have finite (co)-limits.